# Issue with Outlook - Internet working

Tags: networking

We have a lease line connected to a Linksys router. From the Linksys we take it to NetGear and Vonage. Here is the problem i have. When i give obtain ip address automatically everything works fine. But when i give 'use following ip address' and configure the ip, subnet and default gateway outlook does not work and google.com throws 500 error frequently (but not consistently). Most of the other sites work fine.

What could be the issue?

Thank you

NLV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like a DNS problem to me, are you manually configuring the DNS servers?

Comment: Yes. I gave our local DNS server (domain controller) ip as the primary DNS server. When i changed it to ISP DNS address it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the static IP you give is not used by any other device in the network?